# Would it be possible to edit Eclipse commands

Tags: java, eclipse

In my java classes there are some sections called preserved sections, generated by our code generator.

I need to edit eclipse **organize imports**(ctrl+shift+o) so that all the imports that are added are added to those sections.

Here is an example of preserved section for imports in my code:

```
// ---------- <preserved_begin id="fF2sdA.imports" />
// ---------- <preserved_begin id="fF2sdA.imports" />
```

I need all new imports to be added between those 2 lines.

So, for example I have a following situation:

```
import java.util.*;
// ---------- <preserved_begin id="fF2sdA.imports" />
// ---------- <preserved_begin id="fF2sdA.imports" />
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

When I use **organize imports** command I get:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.example.Customer
// ---------- <preserved_begin id="fF2sdA.imports" />
// ---------- <preserved_begin id="fF2sdA.imports" />
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

And, I want:

```
import java.util.*;
// ---------- <preserved_begin id="fF2sdA.imports" />
import com.example.Customer
// ---------- <preserved_begin id="fF2sdA.imports" />
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

I found out that you can make new commands but, is there a way to edit or extend eclipse commands, and if so can you point me to some good literature explaining the process.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in eclipse [help page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-keybindings.htm),

> Ctrl + Shift + O
>
> Organizes the import declarations in the compilation unit currently
> open or selected. Unnecessary import declarations are removed, and
> required import declarations are ordered as specified in the Organize
> Import preference page (Window > Preferences > Java > Organize
> Import). Organize import can be executed on incomplete source and will
> prompt you when a referenced type name can not be mapped uniquely to a
> type in the current project. You can also organize multiple
> compilation units by invoking the action on a package or selecting a
> set of compilation units.

By default the ordering is as follows
[image]

Consider the following snippet before `Ctrl + Shift + o`

```
package com.somepackage.test;
// comment 1

import java.util.HashMap; // redundant

//comment 2

import java.util.Map; // redundant

//comment 3

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

//comment 4

import org.xml.*; // redundant

//comment 5

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//comment 6
```

Snippet after `Ctrl + Shift + o`

```
package com.somepackage.test;

import java.io.IOException; // required and newly added
import java.util.ArrayList; // required and newly added
import java.util.LinkedList; // required and newly added

//comment 3

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

//comment 5

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.somepackage.hello.Hello2;  // required and newly added

//comment 6
```

As you must have noticed, the `Organize imports` first searches for all redundant imports and deletes the invalid imports along with the comments line by line till it hits a valid import. 
After this, it adds all the required imports in order as mentioned in the `preferences` (see image).

So, so answer your question, **there is no way to add imports in between some comments section**. You would have to do it manually.